# How can I build a landing page? What is CloudPages vs Content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am getting my feet under me in marketing cloud and am a little lost. I keep running into situations where things have similar names but they are very different tools. I am trying to determine what tier and plan of marketing cloud my company needs to purchase. We want to build landing pages that hold a form for things such as event registrations or content offers. We also wanted to send relatively sophisticated email journeys to our audience.

As far as I'm able to tell, CloudPages is what we will need to ensure we have in order to accomplish our task of building landing pages, but then I run into some things that I don't understand.

**CloudPages Classic Editor Migrated to Content Builder** -- With the next release, CloudPages created with the classic editor are migrated to Content Builder, and code resources are created from the code view in Content Builder.

Does this mean that Content Builder and CloudPages are different things? Can one do something the other can't? Which one of these is necessary to create a landing page?

I get more confused when I dig in more and landed on pages like this one: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_get_started_with_content_builder.htm&type=5

and this one: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5

and this one: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_use_landing_pages.htm&type=5

The first seems to indicate that Content Builder is used for email (What is email studio for?????), and the CloudPages link seems to indicate that it will "publish to 'Landing Pages'" (What is Landing Pages??) and the third says "How to create a landing page in Marketing Cloud CloudPages."

I am leaning towards the feeling that when making my purchase, I need to find a plan tier that includes CloudPages, but I want to be sure that there isn't another "place" or way to accomplish building landing pages in a lower tier or different plan before I make an argument in one direction or the other.

I appreciate any help and guidance offered in assisting me to better understand what these areas of Salesforce do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Content Builder and Email Studio for emails and Web Studio for Cloud Pages (Cloud Pages is the name that Salesforce is using for landing pages in Marketing Cloud, these two names are used interchangeably):

- Content Builder: build emails and other content that can be used inside emails, sms messages, landing pages, etc
- Email Studio: build, test and send emails
- Web Studio: build and publish CloudPages (landing pages)

You won’t be able to build landing pages without CloudPages (Web Studio) - there is no “lower” tier or functionality available for this.

You do not need any of the 'Classic' tools, they have been discontinued.

And in case you also want to use journeys, you will need Journey Builder.

See this overview for more details: https://www.salesforceben.com/the-drip/what-is-salesforce-marketing-cloud/

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I appreciate your insight! :)